# process.env.anything is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using nodeJs and expressjs. In this application, i used `.env` file to store configuration variables. My Project structure.

```
root>
    server>
          config>
                db.js
   .env
   package.json
```

I kept `.env` in root directory of my project.

#### .env

```js
PORT = 4000

MONGO_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/rocketchat

JWT_KEY=38cb22a391b57e5236fd4048b57622a243d3385d1a93955a6d5f018589ca0e7e6aedf31412b3e25b6c621a432a5b84b1612ce7f9784a145d60623b234dbb98b5
```

#### db.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoURI = process.env.MONGO_URI
console.log("Mongo URI",mongoURI)
mongoose.connect(mongoURI,{
    useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true
},(err)=>{
    if(!err)
    console.log("Database connected!");
    else console.log('Problem  in connecting database!',err)
})
```

I got error.

```
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined".
```

#### console.log

```
Mongo URI undefined
```

Comment: You must load the .env file before using the environment variables. Install *[dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)* and paste ```require('dotenv').config();``` in the first line of the source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first install :

```
npm install dotenv
```

then front of your entrypoit app require that :

```
require('dotenv').config();
```